# For software created with .NET Core Version 2+, that needs to go “live”, is there any reason to install the .NET Core Runtime on the target “live” OS?

Tags: c#, linux, windows, .net-core, development-environment

To clarify with another question; with a familiar process of "My PC" to "Development Environment" to "QA Environment" to "Live Environment", do I need to install .NET Core on the "Development Environment", "QA Environment", and "Live Environment" computers?

What we've tried to do to understand is create two "Hello World" examples:

```
1. A .NET Core 2+ "Hello World" Console application, and
2. a .NET Core 2+ Web API application
```

and run the executable without installing .NET 2+ Runtime or .NET 2+ SDK; and it seems to work.

Admittedly, we've only tried this in virtual machines running Windows and Linux, and without including IIS in the mix.

I want to make a point that I’m only talking about newly created software, and not any legacy software or frameworks.

Comment: I suppose this documentation article should answer your question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: So, a choice between being dependent and independent?

Comment: Yes, you can either deploy only your app binaries, then target machine would need to have runtime preinstalled. Or you can deploy complete package, including runtime itself (though note that runtime might have prerequisites and those still have to be installed on target machine).

Comment: The prerequisites for the runtime you're talking about are things like an ANSI C library installed on the target operating system? (things like that)

Comment: Things like that: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/prereqs.md

Comment: In .NET core 3.0+, this now works by running `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release --self-contained` in your environments

Answer (score 0):

With guidance from a kind Evk:

> > To *run* software developed using .NET Core 2+ on another computer:
>
> - Double clicking an installer that you’ve downloaded for Windows, or
> - running something *equivalent of* `apt-get install dotnet-xxx` on Linux, or
> - downloading and installing a .pkg file on Macintosh
>
> > is ***not*** mandated or required.

A caveat is that the prerequisites (currently located at  https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/prereqs.md) should be met. At the time of writing this represents the modern traditional operating systems.

So, in the familiar “My PC”, "Development Environment", "QA Environment" and "Live Environment" process, this would mean that non-“My PC” computers do not require anything related to .NET Core 2+ to be preinstalled.

A additional source of understanding is currently located at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ that states “*a self-contained deployment (SCD) doesn't rely on the presence of shared components on the target system*”.

So, no, there is no reason to install the .NET Core Runtime on the target "live" OS if it has been created with .NET Core Version 2+.

Comment: As above - this is easy now to achieve in .NET Core 3.0+ without any pre-reqs; something like `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release --self-contained`build scripts.